# Understanding OuterIterator Interface PHP

Tags: php, iterator, spl

I'm trying to implement `OuterIterator` interface on my class but I'm not sure what to use in the method `getInnerIterator`. I know it should return an Iterator but I'm not understanding in what circumstances it should return an `InnerIterator` although it is already has all the methods of the Iterator interface then why does it need an `InnerIterator`?

I'm totally lost with `OuterIterator`

```
class myouterIterator implements OuterIterator 
{
    /**
    * Returns the inner Iterator for the current entry
    */
    public $data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    public $position = 0;
    public function getInnerIterator()
    {
        // What code should be place here
    }
    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->position = 0;
    }
    public function valid()
    {
        return isset($this->data[$this->position]);
    }
    public function key()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }
    public function current()
    {
        return $this->data[$this->position];
    }
    public function next()
    {
        ++$this->position;
    }
}   

$OuterIt = new myouterIterator();
foreach($OuterIt as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key, ' ', $value, '<br>';

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to implement `OuterIterator` at all? It is intended to "iterate over iterators" but your example just iterates over scalar values, it makes no sense to have an iterator for each of them.

If you want to see a practical example of the `OuterIterator` interface, have a look at the [`AppendIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.appenditerator.php), which consecutively iterates over several iterators.